# Finding the probability mass function of

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Consider an information source that produces numbers k in the set SX =
> {1, 2, 3, 4}. Find and plot the PMF in the following cases:
>
> (a) p<sub>k</sub> = p<sub>1</sub>/k, for k = 1, 2, 3, 4. Hint: Find
> p<sub>1</sub>.

I attempted to solve this problem by doing the following.

p<sub>1</sub>/1+ p<sub>1</sub>/2 + p<sub>1</sub>/3 +p<sub>1</sub>/4 =1.

Solving for p1 I got p1 = 12/25 and the PMF to be 12/25k.

However the professor claims that it is p1=8/15. could someone please explain how 8/15 could be the correct answer? The professor's solution can be found at the following link.

https://youtu.be/aWxW9zey1RU?si=6SBn1OyxvrIe0Egb

Comment: The answer provided in the video is simply wrong. That’s all.